# HOW TO: Tell a Module Which Region the View to Register to at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Is it possible to pass on the region name to the module so it knows which region the view should register with?

I see in many code example that the regionName is hardcoded in the module initialize method.

What I want to do is have the SHELL pass in the region name when the module is registering the view to a region.

If this is not possible or not recommended, why would this be a bad or good thing?

Comment: The Shell doesn't "pass in" any region name to a module. The shell *defines* regions that any module may inject views in. I don't understand what you are trying to do but it sounds like the wrong approach.

Comment: How would you load two or more instances of the same modules views into the same shell? For example if I have a "Part Entry" module and wanted to allow as many instances the user wants.  Each instance would load into a dockable tab.

Comment: similar to this: http://4-getful.blogspot.com/2010/04/ensuring-your-prism-modules-can-load.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I, and others, handle the idea of avoiding magic strings being set/passed all over the place, is to centralize the storage of the strings, so you can refer to them on other places.

First, you need a class that will store the string(s). I use one called `RegionNames` for my Prism... region... names. An Example is below.

```
namespace Application.Shared
{
    public class RegionNames
    {
        // Main window regions
        public static string RibbonRegion { get { return "RibbonRegion"; } }
        public static string TitleBarRegion { get { return "TitleBarRegion"; } }
        public static string ToolBarRegion { get { return "ToolBarRegion"; } }
        public static string DashboardRegion { get { return "DashboardRegion"; } }
        public static string ContentRegion { get { return "ContentRegion"; } }
    }
}
```

Once you have this established in a central location in your solution, like an assembly that all the other assemblies can reference, you can use it like below.

```
using Application.Shared;

namespace Application.Modules
{
    public class ModuleX : IModule
    {
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _region_manager;

    public ModuleX (IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager region_manager)
        {
        _container = container;
        _region_manager = region_manager;
        }
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            _region_manager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.RibbonRegion, typeof(ToolViewX));
            _region_manager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(FinderViewX));
        }
    }
}
```

As long as a class can access the namespace that `RegionNames` class uses, they can access the static properties. Nothing to pass this way.

This technique isn't limited to Prism, or C#! You can use this pattern in any programming language. Instead of calling `RegionNames`, call it `StringBag`, or whatever!

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want a different regionname during runtime? For example, if I want to load two instances of the same module, they would need to be in two different regionnames right?

Comment: I think this guys has the right idea: http://4-getful.blogspot.com/2010/04/ensuring-your-prism-modules-can-load.html

Comment: If you want to display a view in a difference region at run time, you can do that via a RequestNavigate. http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/08-Navigation/#view-based-navigation You don't have to set that in stone at compile time. Are you really going to cite a blog post from almost 7 years ago? A bad example at that.

Comment: ??? I was pointing out the concept because I couldn't get my idea across. If the latest version of prism can handle this but in a new terminology then that is what I am looking for.

Comment: I review you link. Thanks. But that still doesn't solve the problem. You still need to define your regions a head of time.  Think of a tabbed application where it loads content dynamically. Tab may load a new instance of the same view but requires a new RegionName since the shell cannot have multiple regions with the same name

Comment: Your question didn't mention the need for scoped regions AT ALL. If you want a solution to a problem, state that in the question. Yes, you have to define regions ahead of time, but the concept of scoped regions will allow you to have a region with the same name open in multiple tabs. http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/07-Composing-the-UI/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the term "Scoped Region" until you mentioned it.  Your link looks interesting. I will take a look at it. Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a service that manages your region names and inject that into the modules.

```
IRegionNameService
{
    string MainRegion {get;}
    string DetailRegion {get;}
}
```

Register your service as a singleton with your container, and now you can have it configured just the way you want it when the app launches and before the modules are loaded.

Comment: I ended up using an EventService for now. But still not satisfied with the solution.